# how to make the panel size fixed inside the modalpopupextender

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Hello, I have two tables inside the panel of modalpopupextender.
I want size of the panel to be fixed whether or not both tables are visible inside the modalpopup.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like as

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAddEdit" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style = "display:none;min-width:20px;min-height:20px">
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: i'm giving width to that panel in the css also.but when for one of the table i'm defining style="display:none" .then the panel size automatically decreases

Comment: see my answer i have add something,i may help you